# Django AJAX form, no POST data in view

Tags: ajax, django, angularjs, post

I have some contact form and JS/Angular code sending it to view for some validation and mailing.

**contact_form.js**

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('contactForm', []);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});

app.controller('contactFormController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
    $scope.contact_form = {};
    this.send = function(form){
        if (form.$valid){
            $http.post('/contact_form_submit/', {'form': $scope.contact_form}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    $scope.msg = 'Twoja wiadomość została wysłana.';
                    $scope.contact_form = {};
                    $scope.contactForm.$setPristine();
                }
                else if (data.status == 'delay')
                    $scope.msg = 'Odczekaj.';
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.msg = 'Wystąpił błąd.';
                if (status == '403')
                    $scope.msg += ' Włącz cookie!';
            });
        }
        else
            this.msg = 'invalid!';
    };
}]);
})();
```

**view.py**

```
def contact_form_submit(request):
return return_json(request)
if not request.is_ajax() or (request.method != 'POST'):
    raise SuspiciousOperation

response_data = {}

# dealing with existing (or not) delay entry
try:
    if request.session['mailer_delay'] > str(timezone.now()):
        response_data['status'] = 'delay'
        return return_json(response_data)
except KeyError:
    pass

# validation
form_data = {}
for field in ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'subject', 'text']:
    form_data[field] = request.POST.items()

# mailing
mailer = send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
request.session['mailer_delay'] = str(timezone.now()+timedelta(seconds=60))  

response_data['status'] = mailer
return return_json(response_data)
```

and the **return_json()**

```
def return_json(data):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import json
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

The problem is i get no items at all in request.POST in view. Firebugs tells me that data was sent correctly, but there's no in view.
Someone knows the answer what's wrong?

Comment: **return return_json(request)** why do you need this line in the second row of your view?

Comment: Ow, sorry, I forgot to mention that. It's just some shortcut. I've edited my question, added that code of that. The second line is for testing, I've tried to get that POST data and they're not there, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah I thought. What I really meant that why do you return with the whole request object before you let your logic run?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i got it. All data was in `request.body`, not `request.POST`. 
Could anyone explain why? I've read the docs, but still it's not clear for me.

Comment: Because you're sending JSON, rather than form-encoded data.